# External OAuth Access for Amazon S3 using Microsoft Azure AD OAuth Access Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-active-directory, boto3

Does anyone know how to authenticate AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) using the OAuth Access Token generated from Azure AD client ?

Need to access the S3 Bucket via SDK, which is already configured with Azure AD SSO.

Steps

1. Generate OAuth Access Token from Azure AD token endpoint
2. Use the Azure AD token to authenticate Boto3

Boto3 guide : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

Similar Guide that I have found is for Snowflake : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html#testing-procedure